# New 'Contact Exported' and 'Activity Exported' activity

Tags: export, activity

One of our clients has noticed that every time they export a contact (Adv Search or via a Report) an activity is created against each contact of type 'Contact Exported' with the date and the staff member who ran the export. They do a lot of exports and its causing a problem.

Has anyone seen this before?
I'm pretty sure its not a core function (or if it is its new). I think someone may have installed an extension then removed it but its left this function in place.

Olly

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of the GDPR extension does this. It records when contacts have been exported for audit purposes.

Comment: Makes sense. Big thanks Parvez.

Comment: I think we added a setting to turn it off, its come up a few times so worth checking you have the latest version etc. If not give us a shout and we'll try to get an option to turn that off added.